# Problema login php, no redirige al location indicado

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un login con php y html. El problema lo tengo cuando aprieto el boton de Login, lo que ocurre es que me hace un refresh de la pagina en vez de dirigirme a success.php
Estoy trabado con esta parte ya que al ingresa el username y password exactamente como estan en el script sigue ocurriendo lo mismo

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    if (isset($_SESSION['Login']) && $_SESSION['Login'] == true) {
        header("Location: success.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['Login'] = true;
            header("Location: success.php");
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Overpass+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="header">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zqpwkLQ.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="l-part">
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
              <input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" class="input-1" />
              <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="input-2"/>
              <input name="Login"  type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta mover esto `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` despues de tu codigo PHP.

Comment: Lo hice y no hubo ningún cambio

Comment: Intenta remover el `action="index.php"`

Comment: tambien probé con esto y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: te aseguraste de que la ruta está correcta?

Comment: si, estan ambos archivos en el mismo directorio

Comment: @MartinBouhier  <form method="post" action="index.php"> el action que tienes aquí te lleva al index.php, prueba cambiando a success.php

Comment: Me lleva directo sin realizar los condicionales

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que cualquier cabecera que envíes a través de `header` en PHP, debe hacerse antes de imprimir cualquier elemento.
En tu caso, como tienes `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` antes de tu código PHP, estas enviando el cuerpo de la respuesta al navegador y luego intentas enviarle cabeceras, que deben definirse al principio.

Otro detalle a destacar, es que, efectivamente le envías al navegador la cabecera `Location`, pero en seguida le envías cuerpo y *confunde*. Para evistar este problema debes agregar una instrucción `exit` luego de enviar la cabecera.

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = "user";
$password = "password";
if (isset($_SESSION['Login']) && $_SESSION['Login'] == true) {
    header("Location: success.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
        $_SESSION['Login'] = true;
        header("Location: success.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

De esta manera le indicas a tu *script* que no debe enviarle nada más al navegador.

Pruebalo y cuentanos si te funciona.

Comment: No funciono, lo probé tal cual me dijiste!

Comment: ¿`$username` y `$password` estan definidos en tu código?, pregunto porque no esta en tu pregunta

Comment: debemos ingresarlos cuando abrimos la url, escribo user en el campo de "username" y password en el de "password"

Comment: Entiendo, pero esos valores se cargan en `$_POST['username']` y `$_POST['password']` cuando haces clic en Login. ¿Pero las variables `$username` y `$password` las tienes establecidas en alguna otra parte del código?

Comment: ¿Utilizas una base de datos o algo parecido para almacenar los usuarios y sus correspondientes contraseñas? ¿O sólo tienes un usuario con su contraseña?

Comment: Nono, solo utilizo el codigo que subi a la pregunta. Lo desarrolle para intentar introducir un usuario y contraseña y asegurarme que los condicionales funcionaran para asi luego que me redirija a success.php pero no logo realizarlo

Comment: Qué torpe, me confundí cuando te respondí. Intenta agregar en seguida de `session_start();`: `var_dump($_POST);`, y comenta el nuevo resultado.

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿el código de tu pregunta corresponde al archivo `index.php`?

Comment: la agregue pero no pasa nada, sigue realizando lo mismo. El codigo se llama `index.php` tambien

Comment: Ya esta, el problema era que no estaba ejecutando apache, lo estaba abriendo directamente con firefox